# re.fullmatch equivalent in pandas text handling

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Is there an `re.fullmatch` equivalent in `pandas` text handling? So far I have only come across the `re.match` equivalent which is `pandas.Series.str.match`.

I basically want to return successful match if the **whole string** in a particular pandas cell matches the regular expression pattern.

Here's what I have so far with `pandas.Series.str.match`:

```
s = pd.Series(['AB', 'ABC', 'PQ', 'PQR'])
regex = 'AB|PQ'
s.str.match(regex)
```

But this returns all elements of `s` as `True` matches when I only want the first element `'AB'` and third element `'PQ'` to match.

Output of above code:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

Desired output:

```
0    True
1    False
2    True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: You need `s.str.match(r'^(?:AB|PQ)$')`

Comment: why do you need regex if your matching on exact matches?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks!
@Datanovice you're right! I could just make a list of the regex elements and use the ```pandas.Series.isin```